# Can i use continue and break in an if statement without any loops in JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: javascript, loops, break, continue

It's well-known that `break` and `continue` can be used inside a loop:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  if (i === 3) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to use them in an `if` statement, to exit the control out of If block or restart the `if` statement?

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: What would that *do*?

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please tell us what the *real* problem is that you're trying to solve, and we will help you with that instead. Also please read (or refresh) [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And lastly don't forget how to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: Thanks but i found the solution, with the help of callbacks

Answer (score 12):

The answer is different for `break` (yes) and `continue` (no).

### `break`

You can use `break` in an `if`, yes, if you label the `if`. I *wouldn't*, but you *can*:

```js
foo: if (true) {
    console.log("In if before break");
    break foo;
    console.log("In if after break");
}
console.log("After if");
```

That outputs

```
In if before break
After if
```

This isn't specific to `if`. You can label any statement, and for those with some kind of body (loops, `switch`, `if`, `try`, `with`, block, ...), you can use `break` within the body to break out of it. For instance, here's an example breaking out of a block statement:

```js
foo: {
    console.log("In block before break");
    break foo;
    console.log("In block after break");
}
console.log("After block");
```

```
In block before break
After block
```

### `continue`

You can't use `continue` with `if` (not even a labelled one) because `if` isn't an iteration statement; from [the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-continue-statement).

> It is a Syntax Error if this *ContinueStatement* is not nested, directly or indirectly (but not crossing function boundaries), within an *IterationStatement*.

Comment: Labelled statements - `goto`'s ugly cousin.

Comment: To note: this doesn’t have anything to do with the `if` per se, it’s about breaking out of the *label statement*.

Answer (score -2):

Normally you can't. You can only use `return;` to discontinue code execution in an if statement.

**Using break;**

```js
if (true) {
  break;
}
console.log(1)
```

**Using continue;**

```js
if (true) {
  continue;
}
console.log(1)
```

Comment: This is incorrect. It's possible to use `break` in an `if`. It's just rare, and you have to label the `if`.